# Evaluating nth derivative at ith value and plotting result

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods

Solved past issue, have a new one. I am attempting to evaluate the nth derivative, at the ith x value, and store it. The motivation for this is to calculate the error that arises from approximating the Runge function using Chebyshev points.

Code:

```
syms x
func = 1 / (1 + 25*x^2);

Errs = zeros(17,200);
i = 0;
j = 0;
for n = 10:10:170
    for x1 = -1:0.001:1
        g = diff(func,n+1);
        Err = (1 ./ ((2.^n).*(factorial(n+1)))).*(vpa(subs(g,x,x1)));
        Errs(i,j) = Err;
        j = j + 1;
    end
    i = i + 1;
end

%n=10
plot(xx, Errs(0))
```

Running this yields the following error:

```
Index in position 1 is invalid. Array indices must be positive integers or logical values.

Error in untitled (line 15)
        Errs(i,j) = Err;
```

I do not understand what is wrong with the index. i,j are both strictly positive. I am not sure if I initialized my matrix correctly, so the error may stem from this. I am not experienced with matlab, so I am not sure if this issue is stemming from another problem. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You initialise `i` and `j` as zero and use them before you increase them, they are not strictly positive.

Comment: Agree with @David, 1. Indexing variables need to be larger or equal to 1 in Matlab (as it states in the error description). 2. don't use `i` as a variable, since it represents the imaginary number in Matlab (type `i` in Matlab without assigning it first). You can read about indexing [here](https://ch.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html)